# Python(Pandas): Replacing specific NaN values conditional on information about other observations in the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, replace, conditional-statements, nan

If have a data frame where each observation has a UniqueID identifying the observation and a ObjectID identifying the object. There can be multiple observations for the same object, i.e. the ObjectID is not unique.

Some observations have Null value for a variable, which however only depends on the object. Thus, if a ObjectID appearce multiple times and has the variable specified at least once, Null values of other observations should be replaced with this value.

I am using Python with the libraries Pandas (pd) and Numpy (np)

Example:

```
sample_frame = {'UniqueID': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7],"PersonID": [3,2,2,5,5,4,4], "Name": 
    ["Alice",np.nan,"Bob","Joe","Joe",np.nan,np.nan]}
sample_frame = pd.DataFrame(data = sample_frame)
sample_frame
```

| Index | UniqueID | PersonID | Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 3 | Alice |
| 1 | 2 | 2 | Bob |
| 2 | 3 | 2 | NaN |
| 3 | 4 | 5 | Joe |
| 4 | 5 | 5 | Joe |
| 5 | 6 | 4 | NaN |
| 6 | 7 | 4 | NaN |

Thus, in the line with the index 2 the NaN-value for Name should be replaced with "Bob".
However, there is nothing to do for the observations below.

I found a solution, which works but seems somewhat complicated to me:

```
dup = sample_frame.loc[sample_frame.duplicated(subset = ["PersonID"]), :]
dup_persId = dup["PersonID"].unique()

name_na = sample_frame[sample_frame["Name"].isna()]
name_na_persId = name_na["PersonID"].unique()

dup_name_av = dup[dup["Name"].isna() == False]
dup_name_av_persId  = dup_name_av["PersonID"].unique()


for i in name_na_persId:
    
    if i in dup_name_av_persId:
        index = sample_frame.index[sample_frame["PersonID"] == i].tolist()
        
        for k in index:
            if sample_frame.at[k,"Name"] is not np.nan:
                name_temp = sample_frame.at[k,"Name"]
                continue
        
        for j in index:
            if sample_frame.at[j,"Name"] is np.nan:
                sample_frame.at[j,"Name"] = name_temp           
        
    else: 
        continue
```

Is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: What's the desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sample_frame['Name'].fillna(sample_frame.groupby('PersonID')['Name'].transform('first'))
```

Using `groupby` by `PersonID` and then calling `.transform('first')` on the `Name` column will return first non-NaN value in the `Name` column in the group that the row belongs to.